# Regularity of Elliptic partial differential equation with mixed Dirichlet-Robin boundary condition, to prove $u\in H^{2}(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, weak-derivatives, elliptic-equations

When I deal with the wave equation with dynamical boundary condition, I am confused by the regularity of the following elliptic partial differential equation with mixed Dirichlet-Robin boundary condition:
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u+u=f, &x\in\Omega,\\
 u+\partial_{\nu}u=g, &x\in\Gamma_{1}, 
\\u=0,&x\in\Gamma_{0}.
\end{cases}
$$
where

- $f\in L^{2}(\Omega),g\in L^{2}(\Gamma_{1})$
- $\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a bounded annular domain with smooth boundary $\Gamma_{1}$ and $\Gamma_{2}$,
- $\Gamma_{1}$ and $\Gamma_{2}$ are disjoint relatively open respectively.

We can prove that there exists a weak solution $u\in H^{1}_{\Gamma_{0}}(\Omega)$ by Lax-Milgram theorem and $\Delta u\in L^{2}(\Omega)$ according to the equation. But can we prove that $u$ also belongs to $H^{2}(\Omega)$?

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Thank you for your correction which make my question more mature! BEST WISHES!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should follow from local boundary $H^2(\Omega)$ regularity, applied separately near $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_1$. Since the two boundary conditions are prescribed on separated regions (which is what I assume you mean by an annular domain), you can localise to one and ignore the other.

In what follows, note that a weak solution $u$ satisfies the weak formulation
$$ \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla \varphi + u \varphi \,\mathrm{d}x = \int_{\Omega} f \varphi \,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{\Gamma_1} (g-u)\varphi \,\mathrm{d}x$$
for all $\varphi \in H^1_{\Gamma_0}(\Omega)$, that is all $\varphi \in H^1(\Omega)$ vanishing on $\Gamma_0$.

For regularity near $\Gamma_0$, we can take test functions $\varphi \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ and observe that the $\Gamma_1$ term vanishes in the weak formulation. Then $H^2$ regularity follows in the standard way by:

- Locally flattening the boundary near some $x_0 \in \Gamma_0$,
- Taking tangential difference quotients to show all the tangential derivatives $\partial_iu$ locally lie in $H^1$ for $1 \leq i \leq n-1$. Here it is convenient that the Dirichlet boundary is zero, which ensures the difference quotients remain valid test functions.
- Using the equation deduce that the final derivative $\partial_nu$ also locally lies $H^1$.

This is standard, and can be found in any graduate level PDE text covering elliptic equations. See for instance Chapter 6, Section 3.2 of

*Evans, Lawrence C.*, Partial differential equations, Graduate Studies in Mathematics. 19. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). xvii, 662 p. (1998). [ZBL0902.35002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0902.35002).

For regularity near $\Gamma_1$, the strategy is similar, involving flattening the boundary and using difference quotients. Here $\varphi$ built from difference quotients will automatically be a valid test function (assuming your cutoff vanishes near $\Gamma_0$), but you need to estimate an additional term coming from the $\Gamma_1$ integral. I will leave this an exercise, but since you are only taking difference quotients in the tangential directions it's just a matter of using the trace theorem to estimate $u$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Thank you for your detailed answer!! Best wishes!